# Bi-linear estimate for free Schrödinger equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the homogeneous Schrödinger equation:
$$ i\partial_t u + \Delta u=0, u(x,0)= u_0(x)$$

Proposition 4.4 Let $\lambda>0$. Assume that $u, v$ are solutions to the homogeneous Schrödinger  equation. Then
$$ \|P_{>\lambda}u\bar{v}\|_{L^2_t(\mathbb R)L^2_x(\mathbb R)} \leq C  \lambda^{-1/2} \|u_0\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)} \|v_0\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}  $$

Proof. See the Proposition 4.4 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0148.pdf).

*Koch, Herbert; Tataru, Daniel*, [**Energy and local energy bounds for the 1-d cubic NLS equation in $H^{-\frac{1}{4}}$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.anihpc.2012.05.006), Ann. Inst. Henri Poincaré, Anal. Non Linéaire 29, No. 6, 955-988 (2012). [ZBL1280.35137](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1280.35137).

> My question is: Is the higher dimension analogue of Proposition 4.4 is available?  If so,  can you provide reference? If not, what one expect?

Comment: As stated it has the wrong scaling for higher dimensions. If my back of envelope quick calculation is right, the $\lambda^{-1/2}$ should be replaced by $\lambda^{d/2 - 1}$ for the equation on $\mathbb{R}^d$ to get the correct scaling; and the left hand side should be replaced by the low frequency projector instead of the high frequency one. I haven't checked however whether the inequality is true.